# Open a file only if not a directory

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-io

On Linux, `open(filename, O_RDONLY)` appears to succeed if given the name of the directory instead of a regular file (though subsequent `read()` calls appear to fail, which is only to be expected).

What's the best way to check if you are trying to open, or have just opened, a directory, for the purpose of failing with 'oops, wrong filename' instead of 'panic, we have a file but read isn't working'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call fstat() on the file descriptor and check the mode of the file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// ...

int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)
if (fd == -1) {
    // open() failed.
}
struct stat buf;
if (fstat(fd, &buf) != 0) {
    // fstat() failed.
}
if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
    // It's a directory.
}
```

This is all portable POSIX code.

Note that you could use stat() on `filename` before calling open(). But this can lead to the situation of the file changing between the stat() and open() calls, meaning you would open() a different file then the one you examined with stat(). Using fstat() provides resilience against that, since file descriptors will still point to the correct file even if it gets deleted.